# in a GroupAvatar, my "max" Avatar does not obey the rules of my theme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, avatar

I'm trying to create an AvatarGroup with MaterialUi, all my avatars obey a previously created style.

All, except the avatar automatically generated by AvatarGroup when the "max" parameter has been defined. :(

```
    const styles = makeStyles((theme) => createStyles({
    avatar: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(4),
      borderWidth: '1px',
      borderStyle: 'solid',
      borderColor: grey[200],
      width: theme.spacing(3),
      height: theme.spacing(3)
     }
    }))

    export default function GroupAvatars() {
    const classes = styles();
    const nameList = ['Alexandre', 'Regis', 'Leo', 'Thing', 'ola', 'que', 'tal']
    const avatarList = nameList.map(name => {
      return (<Avatar key={name}
              className={classes.avatar}
              alt={name}
            />)
    })
  
    return (
      <AvatarGroup max={4} >
        {avatarList}
      </AvatarGroup>
    );
  }
```

it gives me this:
[GroupAvatar with last avatar too big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0GBm.png)

as you can see the last avatar (+4) is way bigger than the others.

You can test the code on website like stackblitz.com using react:
[stackblitz where you can test project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jpx9x8?file=demo.js)

here are the import

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
    import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import { withStyles, WithStyles, createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import { grey, blue } from '@material-ui/core/colors'
    import AvatarGroup from '@material-ui/lab/AvatarGroup';
```

how do i make my avatar "+4" the same size as the other avatars ?

Comment: Can you post a link to a working stackblitz?  I tried to reproduce but I just get an "invalid hook call" https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-smekvu

Comment: of course, it will indeed be much simpler, here using react: https://stackblitz.com/edit/jpx9x8?file=demo.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target the `avatar` rule name for `AvatarGroup` instead of the individual `Avatar` components

```
<AvatarGroup max={4} classes={{avatar: classes.avatar}}>
```

Comment: Thanks. it helped me too. I also changed the fontSize as per my requirement